# Getting child data from JSON when key is dynamic

Tags: c#, json.net

Hi I am getting data from an API, i want to get a value from the JSON returned in the API

```
{{
  "symbol": "NIO",
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "underlying": null,
  "strategy": "SINGLE",
  "interval": 0.0,
  "isDelayed": false,
  "isIndex": false,
  "interestRate": 0.1,
  "underlyingPrice": 9.67,
  "volatility": 29.0,
  "daysToExpiration": 0.0,
  "numberOfContracts": 1,
  "putExpDateMap": {},
  "callExpDateMap": {
    "2021-01-15:195": {
      "20.0": [
        {
          "putCall": "CALL",
          "symbol": "NIO_011521C20",
          "description": "NIO Jan 15 2021 20 Call",
          "exchangeName": "OPR",
          "bid": 1.22,
          "ask": 1.24,
          "last": 1.22,
          "mark": 1.23,
          "bidSize": 48,
          "askSize": 3,
          "bidAskSize": "48X3",
          "lastSize": 0,
          "highPrice": 1.29,
          "lowPrice": 0.76,
          "openPrice": 0.0,
          "closePrice": 1.23,
          "totalVolume": 5636,
          "tradeDate": null,
          "tradeTimeInLong": 1593719978324,
          "quoteTimeInLong": 1593719990155,
          "netChange": -0.01,
          "volatility": 116.363,
          "delta": 0.335,
          "gamma": 0.044,
          "theta": -0.008,
          "vega": 0.026,
          "rho": 0.011,
          "openInterest": 30322,
          "timeValue": 1.22,
          "theoreticalOptionValue": 1.23,
          "theoreticalVolatility": 29.0,
          "optionDeliverablesList": null,
          "strikePrice": 20.0,
          "expirationDate": 1610744400000,
          "daysToExpiration": 195,
          "expirationType": "R",
          "lastTradingDay": 1610758800000,
          "multiplier": 100.0,
          "settlementType": " ",
          "deliverableNote": "",
          "isIndexOption": null,
          "percentChange": -0.81,
          "markChange": 0.0,
          "markPercentChange": 0.0,
          "inTheMoney": false,
          "nonStandard": false,
          "mini": false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}}
```

I am trying to get the child data under callExpDateMap, the problem is the dates are dynamic and sometimes it may contain more than one date.

I thought i could get it using something like this -

```
dynamic oContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(optionDataContent);
var orderData = ((IEnumerable)oContent).Cast<dynamic>().Where(q => q.callExpDateMap.Contains(fromDate.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd"))).Select(x => new { x.ask }).First();
```

However the above does not work, any suggestions on how i can get it.Thank you in advance

Comment: `var orderData = oContent.callExpDateMap.Where ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ to json:

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(optionDataContent);    
var asks = jObj["callExpDateMap"]
    .Children<JProperty>()
    .Where(p => p.Name.Contains("2021-01-15"))
    .Select(p => p.Value)
    .SelectMany(p => p.Children<JProperty>())
    .SelectMany(p => p.Children<JArray>())
    .SelectMany(p => p.Children<JObject>())
    .Select(o => new { ask = o["ask"]?.Value<string>() })
    .ToList(); // or First()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my issue, i appreciate your response.

Answer (score -1):

Declare callExpDateMap as Dictionary<DateTime, Whatever>. If even the key "20.0" is dynamic declare callExpDateMap as Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<double,IEnumerable>.